# Is there any drawbacks in continuing to copy files in background when conflict occurs?

Tags: files, copy-paste

Any time I see this dialog, the whole process stops. It happens in standard OS file manager, FileZilla, MEGA (cloud) and other file managing software. It always bothered me when I can't answer to dialog due to my afk. Why designers of these do not deside to show conflict dialogs in tabs (or another way) without stopping process?

[image: Win 10 Dialog]
[image: FileZilla Dialog]

Comment: Hi DIES, welcome. It's a little difficult to understand this question without examples of the dialogs you're describing. Would you be able to add screen shots? And what is happening in the dialog that is stopping the process when you're AFK? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I think it would be a fairly easy improvement to do all the files that are possible without intervention while maintaining a queue of the files that do require intervention to be sorted out later.

Some systems already do this. For example, generally when uploading files (e.g. to CPanel's file manager or a WordPress installation), they all go in parallel as much as possible, and you learn afterwards of those that failed. This seems like a good model to me.

I suppose one drawback would be that you might not notice that some had failed if there was no prompt until the end. But I think that's a matter of good UI.

Answer (score 0):

Yeh interesting question. I've come across these a million times also and ultimately I just want the job to be done quick.
The way they have it is the easiest method without risking liability of losing or overwriting files the user didn't want to be. It's a blunt interaction that puts the onus on the user, making it very clear what's going on whilst giving them time to think by pausing it all. Bearing in mind that Windows OS is designed with a target user in mind who is not fast paced in their interaction and is not a super user.

Also, on the tech side of it, the way the files are copied in this instance, it's done so by going sequentially through the list of files. For it to operate the way you suggest where it could continue despite errors, it would have to do a complete summary and check of the files and proposed action, report back, and then initiate the copy. In that report it would highlight the potential errors from the action and ask the user in one request whether it should go ahead or not.

Questionable what route would save the most time. Depends how organised the user prior to initiating the action, whether they've bothered to review potential duplicates and copy issues themselves prior to starting the action.